# Internal and external clock synchronisation in FPGA

Tags: fpga, vhdl

My FPGA has an internal clock of 66.66 Mhz. An input is a video signal clocked at the same frequency.

It seems that I can't clock a process processing the data with the internal clock, as I don't know about the phase of the signal, and the two frequencies may not be exactly the same.

I know that I can use a DPRAM to clock the video signal at the internal clock. I have also read that I can use two D latches to synchronise the two clock, but I don't get how it works.

I can't use the external clock because it can't be sure it will always be on.

Then, how can I process external data?

Comment: There's a very good paper on the subject in general by Clifford E. Cummings titled *Synthesis and Scripting Techniques for Designing Multi-Asynchronous Clock Designs*. Search for it over internet (I have a copy of it, but having difficulties finding it online).

Comment: Ah, here they are, scroll down to access it http://www.sunburst-design.com/papers/

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Look into clock domain crossing. There is a large body of knowledge on this subject. That said, on an FPGA you usually have 2 options:

- Dual port fifo synchronization
- 2 Stage register synchronization ( as you mentioned)

Comment: On a bus, you typically apply the synchroniser to the control signals, which are guaranteed to have appropriate timing wrt the data (e.g. cannot happen before ALL data bits are stable).

Comment: What if the external 66.66 MHz clock is slightly faster than the internal one?